# How can i solve my this regex logical error?

Tags: python, regex, dataset

Code -

```
df['Expiry'], df['Symbol'] = None, None
index_Ticker = df.columns.get_loc('Ticker')
index_Expiry = df.columns.get_loc('Expiry')
index_Symbol = df.columns.get_loc('Symbol')
            
Expiry_Pattern = r'-([A-Z]{1,3})'
Symbol_Pattern = r'(.*?)-[A-Z]{1,3}'
            
for row in range(0, len(df)):
    Expiry = re.search(Expiry_Pattern, df.iat[row, index_Ticker]).group()
    df.iat[row, index_Expiry] = Expiry
    Symbol = re.search(Symbol_Pattern, df.iat[row, index_Ticker]).group()
    df.iat[row, index_Symbol] = Symbol
```

here I'm using this regex

```
Expiry_Pattern = r'-([A-Z]{1,3})'
Symbol_Pattern = r'(.*?)-[A-Z]{1,3}'
```

And my output is -
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujObi.png)

And My actual data is in this format -

```
ZEEL-III.NFO
RELIANCE-III.NFO
ADANIPORTS-I.NFO
ZEEL-II.
AARTIIND-III.NFO
```

but I want output -

```
ZEEL         III
RELIANCE     III
ADANIPORTS   I
ZEEL         II
AARTIIND     III
```

I don't understand how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `'-?(\w+)(?=-|\.)'` to get the expected output for the sample data you have:

```py
>>> df['col'].str.findall('-?(\w+)(?=-|\.)').apply(pd.Series)

            0    1
0        ZEEL  III
1    RELIANCE  III
2  ADANIPORTS    I
3        ZEEL   II
4    AARTIIND  III`
```

**Pattern Explanation**:

**`'-?(\w+)(?=-|\.)'`**

- `-?` will match one or zero occurrence of hyphen `-` in the beginning
- `(\w+)` captures the word/substring
- `(?=-|\.)` is positive lookahead to make sure it ends with `-` or `.`

The **Non-regex** solution:

Right split the string first on `.` with maxsplit `n` as 1, then take the value at first index, and split it on `-`:

```py
df['col'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[:-1].str[0].str.split('-').apply(pd.Series)
            0    1
0        ZEEL  III
1    RELIANCE  III
2  ADANIPORTS    I
3        ZEEL   II
4    AARTIIND  III
```

Answer (score 1):

I extract value -

```
df["Symbol"] = df["Ticker"].str.extract('(.*?)-').apply(pd.Series)
df["Expiry"] = df["Ticker"].str.extract('-([A-Z]{1,3})').apply(pd.Series)
```

and create two columns.

now my Output is also the same as I want.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxs1l.png)